# Can I see all the comments left on a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I have a website and I registered a Facebook app ID so I can add a social plug-in to leave comments on Facebook through my site (for various pages in the site).

Can I actually see in one place all the comments left for all the pages controlled by the same app id?

Answer (score 1):

The moderate comments tool should list all the comments of the application

`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=YOUR_APP_ID`